Transform simple FO file to PDF using fop 2.10 and JPMS
I did an example that you may clone by
git clone https://github.com/rolfschumacher/chFop.git
Importing it to Eclipse as an existing Maven project and let it run leads to
Unable to derive module descriptor for org/apache/xmlgraphics/fop-core/2.10/fop-core-2.10.jar
Hence, what do I have to do to make it run?

Does this thread help understand/resolve the issue? Can you state, further details around what have you tried and didn't work still.

@Naman the link you gave too complex for me. I tried w/o Eclipse:
java -p lib/fop-core-2.10.jar:lib/xmlgraphics-commons-2.10.jar:chFop-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar eu.ngopng.chFop.App
but got the same error: Unable to derive module descriptor for .../fop-core-2.10.jar.
How to change that cmd for using -cp instead?

The command is almost similar, while -p treats the JARs to be on the modulepath -cp considers it to be on the classpath. So java -cp "lib/fop-core-2.10.jar:lib/xmlgraphics-commons-2.10.jar:chFop-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar" eu.ngopng.chFop.App shall work.

Yes, that works: java -cp "lib/*:target/chFop-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar" eu.ngong.chFop.App with lib containing batik-all-1.18.jar, commons-logging-1.3.4.jar, fop-events-2.10.jar, xmlgraphics-commons-2.10.jar, commons-io-2.17.0.jar, fop-core-2.10.jar, fop-util-2.10.jar.
Hence, I got to wait for using fop with JPMS, right?

Yes, to make use of these libraries with JPMS you would have to wait for them to be updated to fix the issues in deriving their module description or being transformed explicitly into a module in itself.

See now https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FOP-3223
